# splitting data to folders according to one-hot-encoder values

Tags: python

I have a csv file which contains images name and its label as one hot encoder fashion.
For example the csv file contains:

```
image A B C
P     0 0 1
Q     0 1 0
R     1 0 0
S     0 1 0
```

and my code is :

```
 df = pd.read_csv('/GroundTruth.csv')
image_path = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]: x
                     for x in glob(os.path.join('data/', '*', '*.png'))}
df['path'] =df['image'].map(image_path.get)
```

So I want to create sub directories of named A, B, C which will contain the corresponding images in that folder. How to do that? please help.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Add some code and your effort until now.

Comment: @vishnudev `df = pd.read_csv('/GroundTruth.csv')
image_path = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]: x
                     for x in glob(os.path.join('data/', '*', '*.png'))}
df['path'] =df['image'].map(image_path.get)` Like what do next

Comment: Add it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abc.csv

```
image     A B C
P.png     0 0 1
Q.png     0 1 0
R.png     1 0 0
S.png     0 1 0
```

script.py

```
import pandas as pd
import os
   
data = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
 
def createDirectories():
    for col in data.columns[1:]:
        os.mkdir(col)


def moveFiles():
    indexA = 0
    for x in data.A:
        indexA += 1
        if x == 1:
            readfile = open(data.image[indexA-1], 'r')
            savefile = open(f"A/{data.image[indexA-1]}" ,'w')
            savefile.write(readfile.read())
            readfile.close()
            savefile.close()
        else:
            continue

    indexB = 0
    for x in data.B:
        indexB += 1
        if x == 1:
            readfile = open(data.image[indexB-1], 'r')
            savefile = open(f"A/{data.image[indexB-1]}" ,'w')
            savefile.write(readfile.read())
            readfile.close()
            savefile.close()
        else:
            continue
    indexC = 0
    for x in data.C:
        indexC += 1
        if x == 1:
            readfile = open(data.image[indexC-1], 'r')
            savefile = open(f"A/{data.image[indexC-1]}" ,'w')
            savefile.write(readfile.read())
            readfile.close()
            savefile.close()
        else:
            continue

createDirectories()
moveFiles()
```